# Dual PC pyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm, project, dropbox

Is it possible to run pyCharm projects off Dropbox? I'm using both my laptop and desktop pc daily, and I want to work on my projects on both machines without doing too much moving of my projects and so on.

If it can't be done in Dropbox, what are the alternatives?

Comment: A great alternative is GitHub, specifically its desktop edition, which allows you to clone the same project into each of your local devices.

Comment: Git has a lot of advantages as @Conor pointed out. Try the PyCharm github integration that takes care of a lot of the housekeeping regarding git.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a GitHub account and host your project there. Then clone it to each machine, check in your changes and remember to push at the end of each session. This approach has the advantages of introducing you to source control as a way of managing projects, if you haven't used it before.